# Apache giving css or js when url is incomplete

Tags: apache-2.4

If I browse: `http://example.com/` or `http://example.com/index.php` I get the desired page, but if I browse `http://example.com/index` (or any page without the extension) it will show me the CSS or sometimes the JS in a plain txt file view. Apache 2.4.7 Ubuntu 14.04 LTS. Any ideas why this behaviour is going on? I had a good search - no luck.

I added `AddType application/x-httpd-php .php .html` to the mime types, but it didn't seem to effect the problem.

Heres my default.conf:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
ServerAdmin admin@example.com
ServerName example.com
ServerAlias www.example.com
DocumentRoot /srv/www/html
<Directory />
    Options FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride None
</Directory>
<Directory /srv/www/html>
    AddType audio/ogg .oga
    AddType video/ogg .ogv
    AddType application/ogg .ogg
    AddType audio/mpeg .mp3
    AddType application/x-httpd-php .php .html

    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
    AllowOverride None
    Order allow,deny
    allow from all
</Directory>
 .. rest is just log and pw protect etc
```

changed parts of apache.conf:

```
  <Directory />
            ExpiresActive On
            ExpiresDefault "access plus 12 hours"
            ExpiresByType application/javascript "access plus 10 months"
            ExpiresByType image/jpg "access plus 10 months"
            ExpiresByType image/jpeg "access plus 10 months"
            ExpiresByType image/gif "access plus 10 months"
            ExpiresByType image/png "access plus 10 months"
            ExpiresByType text/css "access plus 10 monthss"
            ExpiresByType image/x-icon "access plus 10 months"
            FileETag MTime Size
    </Directory>
```

Here's the list of installed modules:

```
 core_module (static)
 so_module (static)
 watchdog_module (static)
 http_module (static)
 log_config_module (static)
 logio_module (static)
 version_module (static)
 unixd_module (static)
 access_compat_module (shared)
 alias_module (shared)
 auth_basic_module (shared)
 authn_core_module (shared)
 authn_file_module (shared)
 authz_core_module (shared)
 authz_groupfile_module (shared)
 authz_host_module (shared)
 authz_user_module (shared)
 autoindex_module (shared)
 cache_module (shared)
 cache_disk_module (shared)
 cgi_module (shared)
 deflate_module (shared)
 dir_module (shared)
 env_module (shared)
 expires_module (shared)
 filter_module (shared)
 headers_module (shared)
 lbmethod_byrequests_module (shared)
 mime_module (shared)
 mpm_prefork_module (shared)
 negotiation_module (shared)
 pagespeed_module (shared)
 php5_module (shared)
 proxy_module (shared)
 proxy_balancer_module (shared)
 proxy_http_module (shared)
 reqtimeout_module (shared)
 rewrite_module (shared)
 setenvif_module (shared)
 slotmem_shm_module (shared)
 status_module (shared)
```

Answer (score 1):

Looks like it is the option called Multiviews in the vhost.conf or apache.conf file.

```
<Directory /srv/www/mysite/html/>
                Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
                AllowOverride All
                Order allow,deny
                allow from all
</Directory>
```

removing `MultiViews` fixed the problem.

Although why apache would choose index.js over index.php I have no idea.